# Excel - count running total based on a string value

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet tracking e-mails received from various colleges.  Column A is the name of the college, B is the date and C-F are other information about the e-mail.  What I'm trying to figure out is how can I make column 'G' the total count of e-mails received from that college (i.e. count the # of occurrences of 'Drexel' in column 'A' when a new e-mail is received from Drexel).

I'd also like to figure out how to get the last date (column 'B') based on all e-mails from Drexel.

So my sheet might have 2,500 rows, and I add 2,501 as 'Drexel' and column G would show 74 as the total number received and H would show 10/1/2014 as the last e-mail received before the current one.

Answer (score 0):

The count of emails from a particular college can be done with a `COUNTIF()` formula:

```
 =CountIf(A:A, A2)
```

Where A:A is the column with the colleges, and A2 is the college on this particular row that you are searching for. This will return the number of times that particular college is listed in the spreadsheet.

Your second requirement to get the Max Date is a bit more tricky, and I believe it will require an Array Formula. These are written the same as a regular formula, but instead of hitting ENTER when you are done writing it, you hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (sometimes also called CSE formulas):

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$2500=A2, $B$2:$B$2500))
```

Put that in H2 and hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, it will then get some squiggly brackets around it to let you know it's CSE/ARray formula (don't put the squiggly brackets in yourself. Only CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER will work here).

This formula will search through A2:A2500 comparing it to the college in A2. If it finds a hit, it will grab the value from the respective row in column B. At the end it will be a big list of dates, 1 for each entry where the college matches. The `MAX()` formula will then aggregate that list into a single value that will be the max date in the list.

Copy both of those formulas down your rows and you should get what you want.

Comment: on the array formula that's really just copying the value from the date cell I think.  For example:

Comment: on the array formula that's really just copying the value from the date cell I think.  For example - row 245 had name 'X' and date 10/20/2014.  row 250 has name 'X', date 10/30/2014 and what I want to do is show '10/20/2014' as the last date sent - what this does is show the 10/30/2014 (which is nice in that it updates all rows with name 'X') but doesn't help in quickly looking at 'X' to see it's been 10 days since last e-mail.  I do appreciate the help though!

Comment: Ah! ok So I see now that a new email comes through, what you really want is not that particular date, but the second to last. That's some tricky stuff.